# Escape & character in Freemaker

Tags: freemarker

We use an API call to trigger some automated processes. The info that is needed in those API calls are send through Freemarker. For some reason (or maybe a good reason) a `&` character is turned into `&amp`.

Now, this Freemaker field where the `&` occurs is not static. It depends on user input so sometimes there is a `&` and sometimes not. I guess I have to do something with pasting, but I have no clue how. So, this is a part of the code that handles the pasting.

`"JobTitle":"${requestField?keep_after("Functienaam:<br/>- ","r")?keep_before("<br/>")}"`

So, what I want is that the `&` don't get turned into `&amp` because it is commonly used to determine that 1 person has to departments (like P&O) in our AD and now it will be shown as `P&ampO`.

Hope someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello Damian, thanks for using StackOverflow. Please delete the first sentence of your question. It is the policy here to come straight to the point. Furthermore, please tell us explicitly what you want. In this case, you don't want the ampersand to be escaped. Finally, please tell us which programming language you are using and add a tag for that programming language. Good luck!

Comment: Hi AdmiraalIT, thanks for the feedback. I edited my question. I did add JSON as a tag or did I forget something else?

Comment: JSON isn't a language. It's a textual data-interchange format. Are you using JavaScript? Java? C#? Please add a text-based [mcve]

Comment: You probably can't change how the input arrives, so it sounds like the easiest way to handle this is to look for '&amp' and replace it with '&' before you try to do anything else with the payload.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Well to be honest, I have no clue. This API request takes place in the action sequence from TopDesk. It's using JSON-Based REST-API, maybe that helps?